# Actual and Automated Context Menus are Different Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have googled this question extensively yet no one seems to have this issue. Also, as a side note, I am a beginner at Selenium and Ruby, but I will try to be as constructive as possible with my question.

My task is to gather site information via the context menu of various web elements. The site that I am practicing on is http://pershinghall.com/ due to its use of auto-play and flash--which are two things I am trying to test for. When I view the page naturally and right-click on the background, the elements of the context menu are as follows:

[image]

However, when I automate the process with selenium, the context menu options are:

[image]

Would anyone happen to know why this is happening? My code is as follows.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver' 

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://pershinghall.com/"
sleep(5)

elem = driver.find_element(:id, "background")
driver.action.move_to(elem, 100, 100).click.context_click.perform
```

Finally, the start of the background html element is:

```
<div id="background">
<object style="visibility: visible;" id="flash_container" data="swf/index.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="100%" width="100%"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="noscale" name="scale"><param value="lt" name="salign"><param value="true" name="allowfullscreen"></object>
</div>
```

Much thanks for any input!

Comment: It's working fine in Chrome but only for firefox it is showing the default contextmenu

Comment: It worked but now I can't key down to various options like I could in firefox. Would you happen to know a fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your test is context-clicking on some portion of the screen other than the Flash element you're aiming for -- that second screenshot is Firefox's context menu.

I'm not in a position to try it myself at the moment, but I'd experiment with different parameters in the line:

```
driver.action.move_to(elem, 100, 100).click.context_click.perform
```

Is there any specific reason why you've settled on 100,100? Is it possible that you're overshooting or undershooting the flash element?

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. That is a good idea but I don't believe that is the issue, because there was another example I did (http://www.michelbergerhotel.com/ --which on a side note, is a hilarious site) that also didn't work. This was despite the fact that the cursor was clearly in the middle of the background and there were no nearby elements. Finally, I chose 100, 100 as parameters because I copied the example directly. However, I now realize that those are offset parameters :(. But even when changed it doesn't work.